# Redux form textarea error handling

Tags: redux-form

I notice in a `textarea` field, sync-error handling doesn't behave like an `input` field. For example, after displaying a sync-error on a form's input field the error happily disappears when I start typing in the field. On a textarea field, the sync-error just sits there when I start typing (or when I leave the field).

Basically, onBlur is not setting `touched` to `true` when I exit the field.

What extra things should I consider when dealing with sync-error handling on a `textarea` field in a Redux form?

Answer (score 3):

redux-form ^6.x.x changed a lot of its implementation compared to v4 and v5
If you post you sample code, I can help you better though.

I think what u meant, normal  field works fine but  field

That means your reduxForm(...) works fine, there might be the problem in your error handler function or field rendering function.

I leave simple code example

```jsx
// validate
const validate = (values) => {
    const errors = {};
    if(!values.title) {
        errors.title = 'title require';
    }
    if (!values.categories) {
        errors.categories = 'categories require';
    }
    if (!values.content) {
        errors.content = 'content require';
    }
    return errors;
};

// renderField
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, textarea, meta: { touched, error, warning, invalid } }) => {
    const textareaType = <textarea {...input} placeholder={label}  type={type} className={`form-control ${touched && invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}/>;
    const inputType = <input {...input} placeholder={label}  type={type} className={`form-control ${touched && invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}/>;

    return (
        <div>
            <label>{label}</label>
            <div>
                {textarea ? textareaType : inputType}
                {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

// React render
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Field name="title" component={renderField} type="text" label="Title" />
    <Field name="categories" component={renderField} type="text" label="Categories"  />
    <Field name="content"  component={renderField} type="text" label="Content" textarea={true} />
    <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting} className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

reduxForm({
    form: 'TestComponent', // Name of the form
    validate                // <--- validation function given to redux-form
})(TestComponent)
```